# Python removing the last part of an URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

How can the last part and slash of an URL be removed?

For example, for the following:

```
http://localhost/browser/Folder/Folder2/Folder3/last_element.txt
```

After removing the last element and slash, it should become:

```
http://localhost/browser/Folder/Folder2/Folder3
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic. Show your try as [mcve] and explain what is wrong with it

Comment: "put the url here".rpartition('/')[0]

Comment: @Sadia should submit comment as an answer and it is arguably more intuitive and readable than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

U may try this

```
url = "http://localhost/browser/Folder/Folder2/Folder3/the%20end%20xd.txt"
url = url[:url.rfind('/')]
```

Comment: Very neat and nice solution